# fork variables randomly change

Tags: memory, fork

I want to use execvp to run commands through my program. The user is prompted for a command (exits on eof).

Once the program has a command it forks a child process to process the command while the parent waits for the child to finish.

I'm tokenizing the input to store it in a char* array which is kept track of by variable **'i'.**

Except **'i'** keeps changing its value with each iteration of the while loop.

sample input: /bin/ls -l

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define BUFFER 1024

    int main(){
            pid_t p;
            char* paramList[] = {};
            char input[BUFFER];
            int i = 0;
            char* segments;
            printf(">");
            while(fgets(input, BUFFER, stdin) != NULL){
                if((p = fork()) == 0){
                        printf("Executing: %s\n", input);
                        i = 0;
                        segments = strtok(input, " ");
                        paramList[i] = segments;
                        printf("%s%d\n", paramList[i], i);
                        i++;
                        while(segments != NULL){
                                segments = strtok(NULL, " ");
                                paramList[i] = segments;
                                printf("%s%d\n", segments,  i);
                                i++;
                        }
                        paramList[i] = NULL;
                        execvp(paramList[0], paramList);
                }else{
                        printf(">");
                        waitpid(p, NULL, 0);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more precise about what exactly is going wrong with your program?

Answer (score 2):

You're not declaring a size for `paramList`, but you're giving it an empty initializer list; thus `paramList` has zero elements. And then you're writing more than zero elements into it, overflowing onto other local variables (like `i`).

Comment: Ok that fixed the problem I had with the 'i' variable. paramList is now an array of 10 elements but when I assign my tokens to the list it doesn't work. If I hard code "/bin/ls", "-l" in the paramList it works fine.